# python pandas: convert list of dictionaries to long format panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a list of dictionary looks called data like the following:

```
 {'a.wav': array([ 0.        ,  1        ]),
 'b.wav': array([2, 3,   0. ]),
 'c.wav': array([6,7, 11, 8,   9 ])
 }
```

the number of elements in each key (e.g., a.wav) item is in general not the same, I want to convert it a dataframe of the following format:

```
name  value index
a.wav 0      1
a.wav 1      2
b.wav 2      1
b.wav 3      2
b.wav 0      3
c.wav 6      1
c.wav 7      2
c.wav 11     3
c.wav 8      4 
c.wav 8      5
```

i know that i can convert this to a wide format pd by 
`pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in data.iteritems() ])).T`

but I get stuck on how to convert it directly from the list to long format with the index counting the number of elements in each item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1:

Using `pd.concat` with `GroupBy.cumcount`:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({'name':k, 'value':v}) for k, v in x.items())
df['index'] = df.groupby('name').cumcount().add(1)

    name  value  index
0  a.wav    0.0      1
1  a.wav    1.0      2
0  b.wav    2.0      1
1  b.wav    3.0      2
2  b.wav    0.0      3
0  c.wav    6.0      1
1  c.wav    7.0      2
2  c.wav   11.0      3
3  c.wav    8.0      4
4  c.wav    9.0      5
```

---

#### Method 2:

Using `pd.concat` with `DataFrame.stack`:

```
df = (
    pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=v, columns=[k]).T for k, v in x.items()])
      .stack()
      .reset_index(name='value')
      .rename(columns={'level_0':'name', 'level_1':'index'})
)

    name  index  value
0  a.wav      0    0.0
1  a.wav      1    1.0
2  b.wav      0    2.0
3  b.wav      1    3.0
4  b.wav      2    0.0
5  c.wav      0    6.0
6  c.wav      1    7.0
7  c.wav      2   11.0
8  c.wav      3    8.0
9  c.wav      4    9.0
```